# php PDO script refusing to give useful errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i've got a script which is meant to run a database query, however when trying to run this script i get the error Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /var/www/Quack/doSetup.php on line 209 - 209 being the while loop. I'm 99% sure this corresponds to there being a missing column in my database, however i can't work out which one it doesn't like. I was hoping this try catch system might tell me, it doesn't. Is there any way i can get this too give me more information on what it cannot find?

```
try{
    $query = $db->query("SELECT articles . title FROM articles");
    $query = $db->query("SELECT title FROM articles");
    $SQLGetLogs = $conn -> query("SELECT `payments`.* , `plans`.`name` AS `planname`, `users`.`username` FROM `payments` LEFT JOIN `plans` ON `payments`.`plan` = `plans`.`ID` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `payments`.`user` = `users`.`ID` ORDER BY `ID` DESC");

    while($getInfo = $SQLGetLogs -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo 'true';
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e){echo 'My test failed: ' . $e->getMessage();}
```

Comment: there is no consistency there... first you call `query` on the `$db` object, and then on the `$conn` object?

Comment: Call to a member function fetch() on non-object...$SQLGetLogs is not created before it's used.

Comment: @pala_ It's possible to have multiple connections open.

Comment: possible yes, but unlikely, especially when one of them isn't returning the correct info

Comment: @pala_ The error would be different if both were not valid PDO objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set error mode to throw exception to get them, else only internal error code is set:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. This is exactly what i was after! I'll accept as answer when it lets me in 3 mins.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is complaining that $SQLGetLogs is not a valid object, meaning that whatever you're setting it to is returning an invalid result.

The SQL statement at

```
 $SQLGetLogs = $conn -> query("SELECT `payments`.* , `plans`.`name` AS `planname`, `users`.`username` FROM `payments` LEFT JOIN `plans` ON `payments`.`plan` = `plans`.`ID` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `payments`.`user` = `users`.`ID` ORDER BY `ID` DESC");
```

is probably failing or not producing the output you want. You should run the query manually in the database and check the output you get.

Should the $conn here be $db instead?

Comment: Am i not able to make php display the output of this query?

Comment: Well, it's always best to test your queries on the database before putting them in PHP. That way you can be sure that the query works and avoid debugging that side of things.